# Access ViewModel's ObservableCollection from ContentTemplate while Binding with View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collections, observablecollection

1. I have 2 Views and ViewModels called **SummaryView**, **SummaryViewModel** and **DetailsView**, **DetailsViewModel**
2. I have created **ObservableCollection** property in **SummaryViewModel**.
3. Below code is in **SummaryView** to access the collection and bind it with View.

==================================================================================

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DetailsViewModelCollection}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <HeaderedContentControl>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TabNameICanAccessTheItemsFromCollectionHere.}"/>
            </HeaderedContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <LocalViews:InventoryDetailsView DataContext="HowCanIAccessItemsFromCollection"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

**Problem:**

Unable to access the items from **ObservableCollection** to **ContentTemplate**.
But able to access the items in **ItemTemplate**.

**More Details:**

1. I have a button in SummaryView once the user clicks I am adding items to DetailsViewModelCollection by calling parameterized constructor.
2. Collection is getting created successfully and I'm able access each item and its properties in ItemTemplate section. 
   E.g. I could see multiple tabs are getting created and different  TabName names is coming from the collection.
3. But From ContentTemplate section  is triggering default constructor of DetailsViewModel for entire collection once and that instance is getting bonded to all tabs.

I used the sample and source code from here. http://tap-source.com/mvvm-tabcontrol/
I might be doing some silly binding mistake but couldn't figure out.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you can use `Binding` with RelativeResource to target the `TabControl` and set the Path to `DataContext.DetailsViewModelCollection`

Comment: No King, I tried that it did not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

As a regular process In the DetailsView I was specifying the DataContext as DetailsViewModel.
This is the reason When new tabs are added, a new nullable Instance is getting created and binding to it. When I removed that DataContext, the issue got resolved.

I also posted a simple example in [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Design-Patterns-MVVM-Model-d60c7e4b) for others if they come across the similar mistake.